# Integrate Netlify forms to Hubspot forms with help of Zapier

Tags: netlify, zapier, hubspot

I need to integrate [Netlify](https://app.netlify.com) forms to [Hubspot](https://app.hubspot.com/) forms with help of [Zapier](https://zapier.com). Please provide steps to attach both app forms

- Netlify form
  [image: netlify forms]
- Netlify inside form
  [image: netlify inside forms]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps to integrate netlify to hubspot with help of zapier.

before integration it is recommend that you logged-in to netlify and hubspot application for smoother operation.

### 1. Create hubspot form before integration

1. Create hubspot form. Marketing --> Forms [image: Marketing --> Forms]
2. In forms page select Create form [image: Create form button]
3. Select form type(I have selected standalone form because we have to create custom form and we are not going to use hubspot form.) and select **Next** button
   [image: Form page]
4. Select Blank form and Select Start [image: Blank form and start button]
5. You can select inputs(fields) by selecting **Existing properties** fields or you can create your own by selecting **Create new**
6. Create form same field or you can create field by custom name Yes! you can do that because zapier lets you integrate two different fields.
7. After creating needed fields select update and publish.[image: Create or select input types and create form]

this are the steps you have do first before integrate netlify form to hubspot

### 2. Start zapier integration

1. Open [Zapier](https://zapier.com/app/dashboard) dashboard.
2. In create your own flow please follow steps mentioned in Screenshot and then click on **Try it**  and click on **Get Started** on next page
   [image: Netlify to hubspot form integration]
3. Connect hubspot with zapier [image: Connect hubspot with zapier]
4. Now select site(server) in which your forms are added and click **Next** [image: Select site]
5. Now select the netlify form you want to integrate with hubspot and click Next [image: Select netlify form]
6. If zapier is not showing site or form please try with click on **Refresh list** button. sometime it helps a lot.
7. Now you are in connect hubspot account, click on  **create a new account** and popup opens up. now select account and click on choose account. and popup closes. [image: connect hubspot account]
8. Now select the hubspot account and click **Next**.
9. Now you have a selection of hubspot forms. there you can find the forms which we have created in Step 1
10. Now select the form which you have created recently and click **Next**. [image: select hubspot form]
11. Now select the fields which you have created in hubspot and click Next. some fields are default by hubspot(**note:-** these fields are from hubspot not from netlify. netlify comes in next section) [image: select hubspot form fields]
12. Now you are in mapping screen where you can map hubspot fields with netlify fields. After complete the mapping click Next.(**Note**:- in **Netlify** form there must be minimum 1 record inserted) [image: mapping fields]
13. Now we are almost done. check for mappings and click on **Send test** to test mail. if mapping is wrong just go back and update the mapping. and test again. After your satisfaction just click on **Next** button [image: Send test]
    [image: final zap]

**Finally**
14. Review the integration and click on **Turn on Zap** button. [image: Turn on zap]

[image: Integration done]

And ***That's it!*** Your integration is completed. now you can get get every netlify form data(live) to hubspot on every new netlify submission.